# How can i get the arrays from the JSON file Dynamically for each name

Tags: php, json

I have Json file which contain alot of Arrays. How can i get the the array Dynamically for each person by name like the get Parameter.

**Json**

```
[{
    "Name": "Somename",
    "Lastname": "somelastname",
     "Address": "someaddress",
},
{
    "Name": "Somename1",
    "Lastname": "somelastname1",
      "Address": "someaddress1",
},
{
    "Name": "Somename2",
    "Lastname": "somelastname2",
     "Address": "someaddress2",
}]
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$json_file = file_get_contents('jsonfile.json');

$someArray = json_decode($json_file, true); 

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="product.php?post=name">

 <h3 id="custompage"><?php echo $value["Name"]; ?>

<span><br><?php echo $value["Lastname"]; ?></span>

<span><?php echo $value["Address"]; ?></span>
</h3>

</a>
```

Comment: where is your code you tried

Comment: You can json_encode your data from PHP using 'echo json_encode($someArray);', then you will need to use jQuery to grab that data using ajax.

Comment: Can you provide an example to grab that data using jquery and ajax

Comment: your json is an invalid json, and you will need to add more details about what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$findname = "John2";
$findlastname = "Doe2";

$data = '[
        {
         "Name": "John1",
         "Lastname": "Doe1",
         "Address": "1 Fake St"
         },
         {
         "Name": "John2",
         "Lastname": "Doe2",
         "Address": "2 Fake St"
         },
         {
         "Name": "John3",
         "Lastname": "Doe3",
         "Address": "3 Fake St"
         }
         ]';

       $array=json_decode($data);
       foreach($array as $arraydata)
       {
           if($arraydata->Name==$findname && $arraydata->Lastname==$findlastname){
                $address = $arraydata->Address;
           }
       }
       echo "Adress of ".$findname." ".$findlastname." is:".$address;
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <?php
 $json = '[{ "Name": "Somename", "Lastname": "somelastname", "Address": "someaddress", }, { "Name": "Somename1", "Lastname": "somelastname1", "Address": "someaddress1", }, { "Name": "Somename2", "Lastname": "somelastname2", "Address": "someaddress2", }]';

$arr = json_decode($json,true);

$needle = "Somename";
$keyfound = "";
foreach($arr as $k=>$sub) {
    if($sub['Name']==$needle) {
        $keyfound = $k;
    }
}

echo "name ".$needle." found in key ".$keyfound.";

?>
```